# Writing a Set implementation with a randomElement() method

Tags: java, collections, set, time-complexity

I am trying to write an implementation of `Set` which has an additional method `randomElement()` which returns an element at random from the `Set`. I have based the implementation on `HashSet` for a fast `contains()` method. I have also used an `ArrayList` so that the `randomElement()` method is `O(1)` too - with an `ArrayList` all you have to do is choose a random index.

Here is my code.

```
public final class RandomChoiceSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {

    private final List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Set<E> set = new HashSet<>();
    private final Random random = new Random();

    public RandomChoiceSet() {}

    public RandomChoiceSet(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
        addAll(collection);
    }

    public E randomElement() {
        return list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return set.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
        set.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        boolean result = set.add(e);
        if (result)
            list.add(e);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        boolean result = set.remove(o);
        if (result)
            list.remove(o);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {

            private final Iterator<E> iterator = list.iterator();
            private E e;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return iterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                return e = iterator.next();
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                iterator.remove();
                set.remove(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The drawback to maintaining a `List` as well as a `Set` is that it makes the `remove()` method `O(n)` because the element has to be found in the `ArrayList` first, and then all other elements have to be moved along one place. So I was wondering whether it is possible to write such a `Set` where all five operations `size()`, `contains()`, `add()`, `remove()` and `randomElement()` are `O(1)`?

Comment: I'm not sure duplicating the data is a very good idea. `HashSet` and `ArrayList` already introduce enough memory overhead

Comment: @Dici That's true. I'm mainly interested to know if this is theoretically possible.

Comment: I see. I was wondering the same, it seems you are looking for properties that cannot be achieved simultaneously in an efficient way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to replace your set with a HashMap that maps from your element to it's position in the arrayList.  size, contains, add and random will be the same. For remove you would do as follows:

```
Find the element from the HashMap
Retrieve it's position in the arrayList
Remove the element from the HashMap
Swap the deleted element with the last element in the array
Modify the swapped element position in the HashMap
Delete the last element from the array //Now this is O(1)
```

What makes this work is that you don't need any particular order in your array, you just need a random access storage so changing the order or the data will not cause any problems as long as you keep it in sync with your hashmap.

Comment: Removing an item from the `ArrayList` will be `O(n)` regardless of the fact you know where is the item to remove or not. That's why you should not have a single list containing all the items, but one list per bucket

Comment: Wow. I think this works. I'll need to think about it for a bit to see if I can think of any problems.

Comment: @Dici I don't really know how Java handles the remove(int index) internally if index is the last element. But this is easily achievable if you implement your own arrayList and add a method remove last that just decrement the size of your array size.

Comment: @Amr I think removing the last element of an `ArrayList` is `O(1)`. It doesn't matter anyway. You can just leave the last element there. As long as the relevant `E`s occupy consecutive slots at the beginning of the `ArrayList` it doesn't matter what else is there.

Comment: @Amr that's a nice idea, I don't see why it would not work. Removal at the end is `O(1)` indeed, sorry that I read your answer too fast. What's good with your answer is that you don't have to write a lot of code, however it comes to the cost of using twice as much memory. This is still quite clever, +1

Comment: @Amr mm, sorry to spam you. How do you pick a random item then ? Your mapping is `item => index`, not `index => item`, so how are you going to do ?

Comment: @Dici no problem at all am glad to clarify. Just choose a random element from the arrayList. This is it's only purpose. Generate a random number from [0,arrayList size[ and return that element from the array.

Comment: @Amr oh ok again, misunderstood. I'm slow :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is a functioning implementation, following Amr's solution. Even the `Iterator`'s `remove()` method works, because elements are always swapped in from a later position.

```
public final class RandomChoiceSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {

    private final List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Map<E, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final Random random = new Random();

    public RandomChoiceSet() {}

    public RandomChoiceSet(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
        addAll(collection);
    }

    public E randomElement() {
        return list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return map.containsKey(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
        map.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (map.containsKey(e))
            return false;
        map.put(e, list.size());
        list.add(e);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        Integer currentIndex = map.get(o);
        if (currentIndex == null)
            return false;
        int size = list.size();
        E lastE = list.get(size - 1);
        list.set(currentIndex, lastE);
        list.remove(size - 1);
        map.put(lastE, currentIndex);
        map.remove(o);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {

            private int index = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return index < list.size();
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                return list.get(index++);
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                RandomChoiceSet.this.remove(list.get(--index));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The more I think about this, the more useful this `Set` implementation seems. Although I have not done so in the code above, you can include a `get()` method to get elements by index. Not only is this nicer than the other ways for getting any element from a `Set` (e.g. `set.iterator().next()` or `set.stream().findAny().get()`), but it enables you to iterate over the set with an explicit index.

```
int n = set.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Object o = set.get(i);
    // do something with o.
}
```

I haven't done proper bench-marking, but iterating over a `Set` like this seems to be several times faster than iterating over a `HashSet` using a `for each` loop. Obviously there are no checks for concurrent modification, and this is a `Set` implementation that is more memory-hungry than a `HashSet` (although not as memory-hungry as a `LinkedHashSet`), but overall I think it's pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a custom implementation of `HashMap`, because it requires a fine-grain control. Randomly picking a bucket is easy enough, and you could use `ArrayList`s in your buckets to have random access.

To make it clear, you would implement a classic `HashMap` but instead of using a `LinkedList` in each bucket you would have an `ArrayList`. Picking a random element would be as easy as :

- randomly pick an index `rd0` between 0 and `nbBuckets`
- randomly picking an index `rd1` between 0 and `buckets[rd0].size()`

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example of why the Collections interface should have a `getRandom()` method and why it is a fundamental missing feature in the API. HashSet's implementation of `getRandom()` would just call it's private HashMap `getRandom()` method and so forth until the data representation is either indexable or iterable, point at which the `getRandom()` logic should be implemented.

Basically this `getRandom()` method would vary complexity according to the underlying implementation. But since under the hood all data eventually has to be stored either as arrays or linked lists there's a lot of optimization being cast aside by not having a Collection aware getRandom().

Think, what is a Collection? think can I retrieve a random element from a collection in the real world? yes, and so should it be in proper OO code.

However it doesn't, so you are stuck with iterating through the items in your hashSet and returning the `random.nextInt(size())` element if you can't afford to build your own class.

If you can afford to build your own implementation which seems to be your case, then your suggestion is a fair approach however I don't get it why you implement your own anonymous Iterator, this should do just fine.

`@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return set.iterator();
}`

Comment: The reason you have to rewrite `iterator` is that `Iterator` has a `remove` method. If you just do `return set.iterator();` you're returning an object that can be used to modify `set` without making the other changes needed. In the code in my answer (not the question), I'm really proud of the `iterator` method. Using an `Iterator` you can filter elements out of the set while iterating over it, and it still continues to work.