# Generate unique pairs from collection items in JAVA + StackOverflowError

Tags: java, arrays

I need to find a fast and efficient way to create unique pairs out of array items if there is more than two of them.

My first question is that this code I came up with is throwing sometimes **java.lang.StackOverflowError**, why? I know it is going to deep with the recursive calls in the helper, but how to fix it?

My second question is how to make the code more efficient. I don't need to use array - it could be some other collection type.

This is what I have come up with:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

/**
 * Generates unique pairs from items in array. Each item cannot occur more than
 * once as key nor value.
 *
 * @author lkallas
 */
public class UniquePairs {

    private static final String[] NAMES
            = new String[]{"Aaron", "Barney", "Charlie", "Desiré", "Edward"};

    private static final HashMap<String, String> PAIRS = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Check if there is more than one item in array.
        if (NAMES.length > 1) {
            // Find pairs
            for (String name : NAMES) {
                if (!PAIRS.containsKey(name)) {
                    PAIRS.put(name, helper(name));
                }
            }
            // Show results.
            PAIRS.entrySet().stream().forEach((pair) -> {
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " - " + pair.getValue());
            });
        } else {
            System.out.println(NAMES[0]);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper for finding partner.
     *
     * @param key Name that need partner.
     * @return Unique partner.
     */
    private static String helper(String key) {

        // Get random partner from array.
        String partner = NAMES[getRandomInt(0, NAMES.length - 1)];

        // Cannot pair up a name with itself. Also partner cannot occur more than once.
        if (key.equals(partner) || PAIRS.containsValue(partner)) {
            partner = helper(key);
        }
        return partner;
    }

    /**
     * Random integer in the given range.
     *
     * @param min Minimum value of the random integer.
     * @param max Maximum value of the random integer.
     * @return Random integer in given range.
     */
    private static int getRandomInt(int min, int max) {

        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
Using

```
return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
```

instead of

```
return new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

**EDIT 2:**

Created special class for this kind of operation. Feel free to use it if necessary.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

/**
 *
 * @author lkallas
 */
public class MatchMaker {

    private final Map<Object, Object> PAIRS;
    private List<? extends Object> items;

    public MatchMaker() {
        this.PAIRS = new HashMap<>();
    }

    /**
     * Pairs items uniquely and randomly so that keys nor values are repeated.
     * For proper pairing of Objects it is recommended to provide your own
     * implementation of <code>equals()</code> method. Also bear in mind that
     * you should also override <code>hashCode()</code> if there's any chance of
     * your objects being used in a hash table.
     *
     * @param input List with objects that are paired with each other.
     * @return Map with generated pairs.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException When input List is empty or contains
     * only one item.
     */
    public Map<?, ?> getPairs(List<? extends Object> input)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {

        if (input.size() > 1) {

            items = input;

            for (int i = 0; i < input.size() - 1; i++) {
                Object k = input.get(i);
                PAIRS.put(k, getPartner(k));
            }

            Object k = items.get(items.size() - 1);
            if (PAIRS.containsValue(k)) {
                PAIRS.put(k, getPartner(k));
            } else {
                Object k1 = items.get(getRandomInt(0, items.size() - 1));
                PAIRS.put(k, PAIRS.get(k1));
                PAIRS.put(k1, k);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't pair one or less items.");
        }
        return PAIRS;
    }

    /**
     * Helper for finding a random partner.
     *
     * @param key Object that needs partner.
     * @return Unique partner that is not used by other keys.
     */
    private Object getPartner(Object key) {

        // Get random partner from array.
        Object partner = items.get(getRandomInt(0, items.size() - 1));

        // Cannot pair up a key with itself. Also partner cannot occur more than once.
        if (key.equals(partner) || PAIRS.containsValue(partner)) {
            partner = getPartner(key);
        }
        return partner;
    }

    /**
     * Random integer in the given range.
     *
     * @param min Minimum value of the random integer.
     * @param max Maximum value of the random integer.
     * @return Random integer in given range.
     */
    private static int getRandomInt(int min, int max) {

        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: TLDR, but `getRandomInt` is buggy: you shouldn't create a new `Random` object each time.

Comment: I explained this yesterday. Are you two in the same class or something? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682455/algorithm-for-matching-hashmap-key-with-another-random-hashmap-key-never-duplic

Comment: @PaulBoddington No, we're not! It is not even homework or smth. It is just a piece of code that I wanted to create to make my life easier.

Comment: Ok, well my answer explains what happens. If you run out of options at the last step, `helper` will keep calling itself until a `StackOverflowError` occurs. You need to do a swap if the number of options is zero.

Comment: since java 7 you can simply use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max)` [max + 1 if you mean inclusive] (that min/max method is for some reason exclusive to TLR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
for (String name : NAMES) {
    if (!PAIRS.containsKey(name)) {
        PAIRS.put(name, helper(name));
    }
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < NAMES.length - 1; i++) {
    String name = NAMES[i];
    PAIRS.put(name, helper(name));
}
String name = NAMES[NAMES.length - 1];
if (PAIRS.containsValue(name)) {
    PAIRS.put(name, helper(name));
} else {
    String otherKey = NAMES[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, NAMES.length - 1)];
    PAIRS.put(name, PAIRS.get(otherKey));
    PAIRS.put(otherKey, name);
}
```

What's going on with your version is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33682563/3973077). Essentially, you are running out of options at the last step, so `helper` calls itself repeatedly until a `StackOverflowError` occurs.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help.